# Is there a finitely axiomatizable class of structures whose equality-free theory is not finitely axiomatizable?

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

*(Now asked [at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419472/is-there-a-finitely-axiomatizable-class-of-structures-whose-equality-free-theory).)*

Does there exist a class $C$ of structures which is finitely axiomatizable in first-order logic with equality, but whose first-order logic without equality theory $Th(C)$ is not finitely axiomatizable? Note, if this is indeed the case, then $C$ can't be axiomatized by equality-free sentences.

Comment: In the language with countably many unary relation symbols $R_1, R_2, \dots$, the class of all one-element structures does the job.

Comment: @Z.A.K. True, but really that indicates that we should restrict attention to finite languages in the question.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, I wonder if there is a example for finite languages.

Comment: What about DLO in the language with strict inequality? (I guess you cannot express linearity without equality.)

Comment: @PrimoPetri The equality-free consequences of DLO are still finitely axiomatizable as an $\mathsf{FOL_{w/o=}}$-theory, unless I'm missing something. (The key new sentence is "For all $x,y$, either $x<y$ or $y<x$ or for every $z$ we have $z<x\leftrightarrow z<y$ and $x<z\leftrightarrow y<z$.")

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you, I now understand the question, I think.

Comment: @NoahSchweber wouldn't $ℚ×2$ with "$(x,i)<(y,j) ⇔ x<y$ be counter example? As you can't express $(x,0)≠(x,1)$, you can't state that there is an element between them (it is still "dense")

Comment: @ℋolo The claim is **not** that $\mathsf{DLO}$ is finitely axiomatizable in $\mathsf{FOL_{w/o=}}$, but rather that $\mathit{Cn}(\mathsf{DLO})\cap \mathsf{FOL_{w/o=}}$ is finitely axiomatizable in $\mathsf{FOL_{w/o=}}$ (where "$\mathit{Cn}(T)$" is the deductive closure of $T$). The fact that $\mathit{Cn}(\mathsf{DLO})\cap \mathsf{FOL_{w/o=}}$ has models not satisfying $\mathsf{DLO}$ isn't relevant. (Maybe I'm misunderstanding your comment?)

Comment: @NoahSchweber ah! I see, it makes more sense now, thanks

Comment: Incidentally, to the OP: if this question doesn't get answered here I suggest asking it at MathOverflow.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something obvious, if the signature is finite, can't you always produce an equality-free formula which is logically equivalent to equality? For instance given a $2$-arity relation symbol $R(a,b)$, we can say that $x,y$ are $R$-equivalent when $\forall c, [R(x,c)\iff R(y,c)]\land[R(c,x)\iff R(c,x)]$. A similar trick works if $R$ has a higher (or lower) arity, albeit the formula length grows quadratically. Then we can say $x,y$ are equal if they are $R$ equivalent for every $R$ in the signature; this is a definable formula since we have only a finite signature.

Comment: @JadeVanadium Besides the problem that this can only be defined for relational languages, this formula is *not* equivalent to equality. E.g., consider a two-element (or larger) model where all predicates are satisfied by all tuples; then your formula is also satisfied by all pairs.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Fully agree on the first point. At the time I was thinking you could encode a function as a relation, but this requires a notion of equality in the first place, which is circular; very silly of me. I think there isn't any first order sentence that defines indiscernibility when the signature has functions. Your second point is also true, but only by violating the identity of indiscernibles. Even in a first order theory with equality, you can create a model in which the model's notion of equality is not the "real" equality, so it's only a trivial exception.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what you are saying does not make much sense to me. In first-order logic with equality, you can *prove* the identity of indiscernibles: if $a\ne b$, then they are discernible by the predicate $x=a$. However, your formula only gives “indiscernibility by predicates other than equality”, which is in general coarser. The model I gave satisfies the first order sentence saying that your formula is not equivalent to $x=y$, hence the equivalence of $x=y$ to your formula is not logically valid. This has nothing to do with models where equality is not interpreted as real equality.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek If all predicates are satisfied by all tuples, then all the elements are internally indiscernible. If there are non-identical elements that are internally indiscernible, then the identity of indiscernibles as been violated. I agree that my formula can disagree with real equality, but this happens if and only if the identity of indiscernibles is violated. This exception is trivial, because (as you noted) there are no restrictions whatsoever on the cardinality of the discernibility equivalence classes.